# Nodejs Facebook chat bot for page

Tags: node.js

So i try to make a simple chatbot for my page with node.js. I connected the webhook with messenger successful but when i send the message. it didn't reply. :) 
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
here my code

```
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
var server = http.createServer(app);
var request = require("request");

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Home page. Server running okay.");
});

app.get('/webhook', function(req, res) { // Đây là path để validate tooken bên app facebook gửi qua
  if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === VALIDATION_TOKEN) {
    res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
  }
  res.send('Error, wrong validation token');
});

app.post('/webhook/', function(req, res) {
    var messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
    for (var i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
        var event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i];
        var sender = event.sender.id;
        if (event.message && event.message.text) {
            var text = event.message.text;
            sendTextMessage(sender, text + "!");
        }
    }
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

function sendTextMessage(sender, text) {
    var messageData = {
        text: text
    };
    request({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
        qs: {
            access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
        },
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            recipient: {
                id: sender
            },
            message: messageData,
        }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error:', error);
        } else if (response.body.error) {
            console.log('Error: ', response.body.error);
        }
    });
}

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Chat bot server listening at %d ", app.get('port'));
});
```

i run it on an ide online and here the error

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/runner/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/runner/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:23:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/runner/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/runner/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/runner/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/runner/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/runner/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/runner/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

Please help me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your are facing this `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`
 because you are sending the response two times, to to fix this change it as below

```
app.get('/webhook', function(req, res) {
    if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === VALIDATION_TOKEN) {
        res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
    } else {
        res.send('Error, wrong validation token');
    }
});
```

In for loop you are making asynchronous requests. The functions that are triggered in the for loop will be pushed to call stack but the response that you are sending will be executed even before all the requests are executed. So to send response after the completing the for loop you can change the code as,

```
app.post('/webhook/', function(req, res) {
    var messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
        var event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i];
        var sender = event.sender.id;
        if (event.message && event.message.text) {
            var text = event.message.text;
            promises.push(sendTextMessage(sender, text + "!"));
        }
     }
     Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
         res.sendStatus(200);
     }).catch(function(err) {
         res.sendStatus(500);
     });
});


function sendTextMessage(sender, text) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var messageData = {
            text: text
        };
        request({
            url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
            qs: {
                access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
            },
            method: 'POST',
            json: {
                recipient: {
                    id: sender
                },
                message: messageData,
             }
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Error:', error);
                reject(error);
            } else if (response.body.error) {
                console.log('Error: ', response.body.error);
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code example doesn't really help, but I'm guessing you're using `res.setHeader` after `res.writeHead` or after already sending a response.

All headers have to be sent before writing the rest of the response and once sent they can't be modified.

Comment: An explanation for the down vote would help me a lot.

Comment: Error is because, response is sent multiple times. Error is also clearly explaining that `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.